# Why color changes only in first input area if I write smth

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form with 4 input areas, but the color changes only in first, what's the reason and how could I fix it?

```
HTML
<form>
    <input id="username" type="text" placeholder="username" value="">
    <input id="email" type="email" placeholder="email" value="">
    <input id="password" type="password" placeholder="password" value="">
    <input id="passwordRepeat" type="password" placeholder="repeat your password" value>
</form>

JS
var input = document.querySelector("input");
input.addEventListener("input", function() {

  if (input.value.length > 0)
    input.style.background = "#27ae60";
  else
    input.style.background = "none";
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`document.querySelector` will only return the first element to match a selector.

What you actually want to do is map through them all using `querySelectorAll`, and add it to each:

```
document.querySelectorAll('input').forEach(function(input) {
  input.addEventListener('input', function() { 
    if (input.value.length > 0)
      input.style.background = "#27ae60";
    else
      input.style.background = "none";
    }
  });
});
```

EDIT: Ok, so some of y'all want a best practice answer. Here you go (The JS anyway. Can add accessibility attributes to HTML to make it more best practice):

```
//HTML
<form id="form-signup">
    <input id="username" type="text" placeholder="username" value="">
    <input id="email" type="email" placeholder="email" value="">
    <input id="password" type="password" placeholder="password" value="">
    <input id="passwordRepeat" type="password" placeholder="repeat your password" value>
</form>

//JS
const signupForm = document.getElementById('form-signup');

signupForm.addEventListener('input', event => {
  const target = event.target;

  target.value.length > 0 ? 
  target.style.background = "#27ae60" :
  target.style.background = "none";
});
```

EDIT 2: Actually, best practice might be pure css. Assuming this styling is to show that an input is properly filled in, you could give it validation attributes ie:

```
<input minlength="1" required></input>
```

and then apply css to style valid inputs:

```
form input:valid {
  background: #27ae60;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you could add a code example showing how they might use querySelectorAll to fix their problem as well?

Comment: Perhaps you could add an example that uses event bubbling instead, where you add the listener to the form element and use event.target to get the field that changed? That way you don't add more than 1 event listener to solve this which is a good habit to learn, specially for bigger forms

Comment: yep, the last version of code is fully correct, thank you so much! and remove penultimate "}"

Comment: @Milton here's your best practice answer below :)

Comment: Oh, there's a pure css way to do it too. Included at the bottom. Objectively the best way.

Comment: I'm nitpicking, but in your bubbling example, it should be target in both places (just so those who copy paste get the right code), and the CSS will only work if there is some other validation attributes (min-length etc) on the HTML inputs but great addition!

Comment: No, nitpick away. It's good practice and I totally forgot to change them after copy/pasting from my first answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to modify your JS such that it adds the `eventListners` to all the inputs -:

```
document.querySelectorAll("input").forEach(input => {
    input.addEventListener("input", function() {
        if (input.value.length > 0)
            input.style.background = "#27ae60";
        else   input.style.background = "none";
     })
})
```

Also we can use event bubbling which is more preferable as it reduces number of event listeners, something like this -:

```js
document.getElementById("signup").addEventListener("change", (e) => {
  if (e.target.value.length > 0)
    e.target.style.background = "#27ae60";
  else
    e.target.style.background = "none";
})
```

```html
<form id="signup">
    <input id="username" type="text" placeholder="username" value="">
    <input id="email" type="email" placeholder="email" value="">
    <input id="password" type="password" placeholder="password" value="">
    <input id="passwordRepeat" type="password" placeholder="repeat your password" value>
</form>
```

Comment: It would be better to use `forEach` instead of `map`. Why bother creating a whole new array?

Comment: Perhaps you could add an example that uses event bubbling instead, where you add the listener to the form element and use event.target to get the field that changed? That way you don't add more than 1 event listener to solve this

Comment: Thank you so much! It's just wonderful, I'm incredibly pleased to see such a good-natured community

Answer (score 0):

That happens because `document.querySelector()` only return the *first* element that matches the selector. You can use `document.querySelectorAll()` or, in this specific case, `document.getElementsByTagName`. Either way, you need to then iterate over the array those functions return.

```js
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input"); // You could also use document.querySelectorAll("input");

function listener() {
  if (input.value.length > 0)
    input.style.background = "#27ae60";
  else
    input.style.background = "none";
})

for (input of inputs) {
  input.addEventListener("input", listener);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It's just wonderful, I'm incredibly pleased to see such a good-natured community